# Sqlite, verificar a diferença exata entre uma data, hora e minutos da data atual

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

Preciso fazer uma verificação entre duas datas, preciso verificar se a data, hora e minutos de um campo é maior ou igual a data, hora e minutos atual, estou usando o [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite).

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE strfTime ('%s', dataFinal ) >= strfTime('%s', 'now');
```

Se esta condicão for verdadeira, os dados vai para o `datagridview_2` senão continua no `datagridview_1`.

Resumindo:
O `datagridview_2` só vai receber informações caso a data atual for maior ou igual a data da coluna "dataFinal". Esta data `Final`, o usuário que vai especificar no campo.

Answer (score 1):

O **SQLite** não possui um tipo padrão para armazenar data e hora. 
Você pode encontrar mais informações aqui: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Porém, funções internas permitem armazenar esse tipo de dados usando **TEXT, REAL ou INTEGER**. Para essa resposta vou utilizar o formato de dados mais comum para armazenar datas no SQLite - **TEXT**.

Para fazer a verificação entre duas datas, você pode enviar um parâmetro na sua consulta através do método **AddWithValue**(). Isso vai evitar SQLInjection. No exemplo abaixo, faço uso do padrão ISO8601 que é uma norma internacional para armazenadar data e hora. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre isso aqui:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier

Segue o código.

```
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"sua_conexao_aqui"))
        {
            string consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE dataFinal > @dataFinal";

            DateTime dataFinal = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

            using (SQLiteCommand commandReader = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, connection))
            {
                commandReader.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFinal", dataFinal.ToString("o")); //ISO8601
                SQLiteDataReader reader = commandReader.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DateTime suaData = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);
                }
            }
        }
```